# Screen fading and battery icon outlined in red

Tags: battery, screen

I've got a new Doogee S40 running Android 9.0.
A problem started when the battery level went down to 20%. The battery icon started to be outlined in red and the screen started dimming after around 5 seconds.

I ensured the following:

1. Screen saver was and is 2 minutes
2. Battery Saver is off
3. Battery Manager is off
4. Standby Intelligent Power Saving is off

I have restarted the phone more than 5 times since this began. There has been no change in the red outline or screen fading.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be corrected?

Comment: You mention a full charge after setting the power saver. I am assuming, since you do not mention it explicitly, that a restart never occurred? Maybe the setting can be turned ON immediately, but OFF, once on, requires a restart. (Pure supposition, mind you). I only ask this because I am a long-time believer that restarts don't always NEED to happen, except under justification; turning this OFF might be a setting that needs an environment refresh.

Comment: I've restarted it 5 times now.  The problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

SUCCESS! I went into Safe Mode. I found the app "Power Saving Mode" and sure enough, it was in "Super Mode" so I changed it to "Normal" and the phone righted itself!

Power Saving Mode seems to be an app built in to Android 9.0, maybe by Doogee as part of their package?

Here is the logo:
[image]

And here is a link with some info:  https://www.techrepublic.com/article/let-power-saving-mode-keep-your-battery-from-draining-too-quickly/

Comment: Just curious, is "Power Saving Mode" an app? If so, is it a system app or a 3rd-party app? Could you [edit] and expand the answer with more details about this app?

Comment: Here's another link, to add to the one I shared above. 
 https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00079037/#:~:text=First%2C%20navigate%20to%20Settings%2C%20and,background%20network%20usage%20and%20syncing.